# How to use backspace escape sequence in Notepad++?

Tags: string, escaping, notepad++

I need to use find new lines (`\n`) in a `.txt` file and replace them with a backspace (`\b`). Using this in the Find and Replace feature of Notepad++ successfully finds the new lines, (`\n`), but replaces them with the characters "\b" instead of applying a backspace. How can this be done correctly?

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use backspace as a line delimiter, replace \n with empty string.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I did that, and it shows that /n was successfully replaced, but Notepad++ still shows separate lines..

Comment: Did you look for \r as well?

Answer (score 20):

`\r\n` should work.

replace them with empty field and you will get your backspace(`\b`) equivalent

Comment: A lifesaver and also a true answer!

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or Edit->Line Operations->Join Lines

I was also trying to replace \n with backspace, but the above solutions seems neat. Maybe it helps someone.

(I tried the \r\n solution and it seems both works the same way :) )

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++,

Go to Edit menu, line operations and then click on "Remove Empty Lines"
You get what you are trying with regular expression.

Removing empty lines

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions, in **Find what:**, enter `\r\n` and in **Replace with:** leave that blank.